# Multiprocessing slows with large numpy arrays used inside

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I've got a problem that when I use large numpy arrays inside my function that I use with `multiprocessing`, each process is 10x slower than when I'm using it on a single process. My function looks like:

```
def func_try(dataframe):
    with open('./array_emb.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        array_emb = pickle.load(f) # shape: (1157055, 128)

    with open('./array_emb_prec.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        array_emb_prec = pickle.load(f) # shape: (113358, 128)

    with open('./array_id.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        array_id = pickle.load(f) # shape: (113358,)

    dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    k = len(array_emb_prec)
    dictionary_calc = {}

    #start = time.time()
    for i, item in dataframe.iterrows():
        dist = torch.tensor(distance.cdist(array_emb[item['idx']], array_emb_prec, 'euclidean'))
        topk = dist.topk(k, 1, largest=False)

        topk_1 = topk[1].reshape(1, -1)[0]
        topk_0 = topk[0].reshape(1, -1)[0]
        arg_topk0 = np.argsort(topk_0)
        topk_1_args = pd.unique(topk_1[arg_topk0].numpy())
        topk_1_args = topk_1_args[~np.isin(topk_1_args, item['check'])]

        dictionary_calc[item['id']] = array_id[topk_1_args[:24]]

        '''if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(str(i) + ': ' + str(time.time() - start))
            print('')
            start = time.time()'''

    return dictionary_calc
```

I checked times with this commented lines. When I use this function with `num_processes = 1` it takes about 70 s per each 1000 iterations inside it, but when I use it with `multiprocessing` it takes about 700 s per each 1000 iterations inside every process. When I set `num_processes = 5` it takes about 210 s per each 1000 iterations inside every process so still more than a single one.

My `multiprocessing` code looks like:

```
num_processes = 20
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
chunk_size = int(len(df)/num_processes) + 1
chunks = [df.iloc[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(df), chunk_size)]
result = pool.map(func_try, chunks)
```

Do you have any idea what causes such behaviour? Could it be something connected with large numpy arrays used inside of my function? I checked it also with passing these numpy arrays into function instead of loading them at the beginning, but that didn't help.

I use worker with 40 CPU and 200 GB RAM.

EDIT:

I tried it also with smaller numpy arrays used inside, and there was a smaller difference between time from single process and times from processes from `multiprocessing`, but still was.

Comment: Interprocess computation is very slow. Thus, if the dataframe is big, it can be slower in parallel, unless the computation is very intensive. Moreover loading the same file in each process is slow as with N processes, the input files are loaded N times and storage device are generally slow (much more than the RAM or CPU caches).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I understand that, but I think that's not my case - loading files takes about 0.01 s so it's not a problem. I tried also passing these arrays as parameters and it didn't help.